# MVC 5 How to Validate Nullable Integers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

This has been asked and answered numerous times, but I have a special situation where I have nullable integers in my model.

**Model:**

```
[Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid integer number")]
public int? Jan { get; set; }
```

In my edit form, if enter "x", then the browser default error pop-up with "Please enter a number" appears. My own client-side validation doesn't appear to be kicking in. If I enter nothing, then it blows up server-side because a parameter was expected in my repository code.

I need it to validate non-integers on the client and I also need it to handle nulls, when someone tries to submit the form with an empty value. I cannot resort to a Required data annotation, because if I do, no data will be loaded. This is a conversion from legacy code to MVC.

**UPDATE - CLARIFICATION:**

I'm dealing with a lot of nullable ints. The decision to try and make them required was mine - am open to alternative options. I cannot change the int? in the model for various reasons. So, I need to validate against nulls on the client and server to ensure that integers are entered.

Comment: Can you specify a clear validation specification. What is allowed and when is allowed? What are you trying to do is not clear in the question.

Comment: @Mat J, only a valid integer is allowed. Plus I want to trap nulls on the client. My only other alternative is to change a lot of server code.

Comment: @Ryan Wilson, if you read the question it says this was a conversion from legacy code. I'm really looking to see if there's a quick client-side hack to trap the nulls and ensure ints.

Comment: I didn't make it nullable. I inherited it. As a last resort, I may end up having to change a lot of server code. There are many such nullable ints in the app and I'm simply looking for an alternative way of dealing with this if at all possible ;-)

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I added some clarification to the question.

Comment: @Ryan, that worked. I guess due diligence would dictate that I provide validation on the server also. If you want to post a complete answer to include that, feel free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the HTML5 `required` attribute client side to prevent empty values from being entered. If you really want to ensure no empty values are sent to the server, I believe you are going to need to do some server side validation as well.

[HTML5 Required Attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required)

Comment: I would combine this with `type="number"` to handle non-numbers

Comment: @Magnetron It sounds like the OP already is validating non numerics successfully: "if enter "x", then the browser default error pop-up with "Please enter a number" appears."

Comment: Ok, I was just confused by OP next sentence _My own client-side validation doesn't appear to be kicking in_, I thought that mean that the pop-up they were referencing was a server-side validation.

Comment: @Magnetron I'm a bit confused by the wording too. I don't disagree with you though. Nothing wrong with doing what you proposed.

Comment: "Please enter a number" is the default browser message. The "Please enter valid integer number" from the model doesn't display. So the MVC client validation isn't working.

Comment: @Magnetron type="number" introduces those annoying up/down arrows.

Comment: @IrishChieftain what's the problem with the arrows? The user doesn't have to usem them and they provide a easy way to increment/decrement.